# Search Multiple Fields in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, multivalue

I've been trying to make the value from a text box search across all fields in my form "Dashboard". The dashboard has 15 fields to search through. I've gone online and tried every example but none seem to work for me. Below is the code that has come closest to what I want, but it outputs to a listbox. I have a continuous form that needs to be searched not a listbox.

Example Code:

```
Private Sub cmdKeywordSearch_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
SearchFor.SetFocus


'Create a string (text) variable
    Dim vSearchString As String

'Populate the string variable with the text entered in the Text Box SearchFor
    SearchFor.SetFocus

    vSearchString = SearchFor.Text

'Pass the value contained in the string variable to the hidden text box SrchText,
'that is used as the search criteria for the Query QRY_SearchAll
    SrchText.value = vSearchString

'Requery the List Box to show the latest results for the text entered in Text Box SearchFor
'NEED THIS TO SEARCH THE FORM NOT A LIST BOX
   ' Me.SearchResults.Requery
    Dim frm As Form: Set frm = Forms!Dashboard
    frm.Requery



'Tests for a trailing space and exits the sub routine at this point
'so as to preserve the trailing space, which would be lost if focus was shifted from Text Box SearchFor
    If Len(Me.SrchText) <> 0 And InStr(Len(SrchText), SrchText, " ", vbTextCompare) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Set the focus on the first item in the list box
'NOT USING A LIST BOX BUT INSTEAD A CONTINOUS FORM NAMED DASHBOARD
    Me.SearchResults = Me.SearchResults.ItemData(1)
    Me.SearchResults.SetFocus
    frm.Requery


'Requery the form to refresh the content of any unbound text box that might be feeding off the record source of  the List Box
    DoCmd.Requery

'Returns the cursor to the the end of the text in Text Box SearchFor
    Me.SearchFor.SetFocus

    If Not IsNull(Len(Me.SearchFor)) Then
        Me.SearchFor.SelStart = Len(Me.SearchFor)
    End If
End Sub
```

My next try which worked only if I used a few fields. When I put all the fields in the SQL string I get the error 3075. I thought going the SQL method was best but it errors. Here is it:

```
Forms![Dashboard].RecordSource = "SELECT DISTINCT ProposalTracker3.*, ProposalTracker3.Status, ProposalTracker3.GACP FROM ProposalTracker3 " _
& "WHERE (((ProposalTracker3.Status) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR (((ProposalTracker3.GACP) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR (((ProposalTracker3.Status) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[GACP Charge Number]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Proposal Title]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Anticipated Submittal Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Expected Contract Award Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Customer Name]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Program Manager]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Proposal Manager]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Project Engineer]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[BAM POC]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*') OR ((ProposalTracker3.[PCE POC]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*') OR ((ProposalTracker3.[PLCS PCE Assigned]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[BPA Pre-KO Notifiction Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[KO Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*') OR ((ProposalTracker3.[BOE/BE Due Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[BOE Submit Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Route Memo By Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*') OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Memo Due Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Memo Submit Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[PLCS Group]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*') OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Estimator 1]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Estimator 2]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Hours Bid]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Budgeted Hours On Contract]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Executed Hours]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.Notes) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.Description) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*'))  " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Proposal Type]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Business Group]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.Organization) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.Competitive) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.Direct) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Proposal Value]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Contract Award Date]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Contract #]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Contract Value]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) OR ((ProposalTracker3.[Contract Type]) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*')) " _
& "OR ((ProposalTracker3.Phase) Like '*" & Me.SearchFor & "*'));"
```

I appreciate your guidance on this.
Maxine

Comment: A quick google shows error 3075 is for Syntax error (missing operator). You've likely got a misspelled column name somewhere, or need brackets somewhere, or are missing a `'`. We can't really help you debug that. You could start by removing all the conditions in your query, making sure it works, then slowly adding them back in until it stops working, so you can figure out where your issue is.

Comment: Are all of your fields Text types?  I'm not sure you can use `Like` on dates/numbers

Comment: Does your search term include single or double quotes?

Comment: @JoshEller was correct there was a syntax error in the expression.